# How to resolve NoMethodError in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a login page and i want to login by submitting the email id ans password.But when i am putting the right email id and password i am getting some error which are given below.

Error:

```
NoMethodError in SessionsController#create
undefined method `authenticate' for #<Class:0x502b300>
```

Extracted source (around line #6):

```
  def create
    user = User.where(:email => params[:session][:email].downcase).first
    if user && User.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     redirect_to:action => 'users/show'
    else
     render 'new'
  end
```

Rails.root: `c:/Site/loginuser`

I am giving all my code snippet below.

In app/views/users/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(:session, url:"add" ) do |f| %> 
                                <h1>Log in</h1> 
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="username" class="uname" data-icon="u" > Your email or username </label>
                                    <%= f.text_field:email,placeholder:"Enter your registered email" %>
                                </p>
                                <p> 
                                    <label for="password" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p"> Your password </label>
                                    <%= f.password_field:password,placeholder:"Enter your password" %>
                                </p>
                                <p class="keeplogin"> 
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="loginkeeping" id="loginkeeping" value="loginkeeping" /> 
                                    <label for="loginkeeping">Keep me logged in</label>
                                </p>
                                <p class="login button">
                                    <%= f.submit:"Login" %>                             
                                </p>
                                <p class="change_link">
                                    Not a member yet ?
                                    <a href="#toregister" class="to_register">Join us</a>
                                </p>
                            <% end %>
```

In app/controller/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end
  def create
 user = User.where(:email => params[:session][:email].downcase).first
  if user && User.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  redirect_to:action => 'users/show'
  else
    render 'new'
  end
  end
end
```

In config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  get 'users/new'

  get 'users/show'
  post   'users/add'   => 'sessions#create'
  resources:users
  resources :sessions


end
```

Can anybody please help me for resolving this problem.?

Comment: Do you have class method `authenticate` defined for your `User` class?

Comment: Or do you have `bcrypt-ruby` gem installed and `has_secure_password` in the `User` class if you're using that

Comment: can you show us your user model? (user.rb)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified whether you have a method by name authenticate in user.rb.

If you have that method already in user.rb, make sure you use **self.authenticate** rather than simple **authenticate** in the method defination.

Reason for the above is that,While creating a method in Ruby Class, you need to associate that method with that class's instance in order to access that method out of that Class.

Refer this link for more info  http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/